# How to remove inline style from img tag using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have tried everything to remove the inline style from `<img>` tags in a page. And nothing has worked.

Given rendered html like:

```
<p><img alt="" src="../../../../images/Cuffs.jpg" style="width: 620px; height: 395px;" /></p>
```

How can I remove the `<style>` attribute from all images in page? I have tried `removeAttr` as well as code from various SO posts and nothing has worked.

**EDIT:**

I tried

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('img').each(function () {
            $(this).removeAttr('style')   
        });
    });
</script>
```

And:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('img').removeAttr("style")
     });
</script>
```

And

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('img').attr('style', '');
    });
</script>
```

As well as about 3 or 4 other examples from around the web.

When I view source I see:

```
 <p><img alt="" src="../../../../images/Cuffs.jpg" style="width: 620px; height: 395px;" /</p>
```

Checking in Chrome

Comment: $('img').attr('style', '');

Comment: `$("img").removeAttr("style");` didnt work?

Comment: You sure you used removeAttr correctly?  The attribute name would be "style", not "width" or anything inside the style.

Comment: If you say it didn't work, show me the code!

Comment: You don't show your JS, but possibly you're running outside of a document ready handler, i.e. before the elements are ready.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first try works perfectly:

```js
$(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('img').each(function () {
        $(this).removeAttr('style')

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
 <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/32/32" style="width: 620px; height: 395px;" />
</p>
```

Comment: When I view source I still see the style attr. I even hit Crtl F5 to see if that made a difference.

Comment: Source or DOM? Because jQuery only affects the DOM not the source.

Comment: In the source. So is the attribute actually gone then?

Comment: @AshokPadmanabhan The attribute makes the image 620 pixels wide.. so yes, it's gone :)

Answer (score 2):

`$().removeAttr('style');` works in Safari, Chrome and Firefox (all latest).  Not sure on IE, but it certainly should.

```
$(function() {
   $('img').removeAttr("style");
});
```

See this jsBin: http://jsbin.com/yokaxo/1/

Answer (score 1):

In my case the images had their 'height' and 'width' attributes set, so instead of targeting the 'style' attribute, you may need to do this:

```
$('img').each(function ()
{
    $(this).removeAttr('width');
    $(this).removeAttr('height');
});
```

Of course you could also remove the style attribute too for completeness, but that's up to you.

```
$('img').each(function ()
{
    $(this).removeAttr('width');
    $(this).removeAttr('height');
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
});
```

Anyway, hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.removeAttr()` method ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)).